# Jolt Spec - Need help in getting Flattened Array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am having some trouble with flattening the JSON.  I have looked at examples and didn't get any closer as to what is mentioned above. I need to transform a JSON structure by using a JOLT spec. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below.

JSON **Input** for a sample :

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp": "XXXXX"
  },
  "data": {
    "product": {
      "id": "XXXXX"
    },
    "storageLocations": [
      {
        "id": "XXXXX",
        "stocks": [
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "dateModified": "XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXXX",
        "stocks": [
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "dateModified": "XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXXX",
        "stocks": [
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "stockStatus": "XXXXX",
            "quantity": [
              {
                "uom": "XXXXX",
                "isoUom": "XXXXX",
                "amount": "XXXXX"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "dateModified": "XXXXX"
      }
    ],
    "dateModified": "XXXXX",
    "temporaryNegativeStock": "XXXXX"
  }
}
```

the tried ***Jolt Spec*** is :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "storageLocations": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,metadata.timestamp)": "[&1].LastUpdated",
            "@(2,product.id)": "[&1].MaterialCode",
            "@(2,product.baseUoM)": "[&1].BaseUoM",
            "@(2,product.isoBaseUom)": "[&1].ISOBaseUoM",
            "@(2,location.id)": "[&1].LocationId",
            "@(id)": "[&1].StorageLocationId",
            "@(dateModified)": "[&1].StorageLocationLastUpdated",
            "stocks": {
              "*": {
                "quantity": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(amount)": "[&5].StockAmount",
                    "@(isoUom)": "[&5].StockISOUoM",
                    "@(uom)": "[&5].StockUoM",
                    "@(2,stockStatus)": "[&5].StockStatus"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Ouput** we are getting

```json
[
  {
    "LastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "MaterialCode": "na-XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationId": "XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationLastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "StockAmount": [
      "0.000",
      "0.000",
      "0.000"
    ],
    "StockISOUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockStatus": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ]
  },
  {
    "LastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "MaterialCode": "na-XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationId": "XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationLastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "StockAmount": [
      "0.000",
      "0.000",
      "0.000"
    ],
    "StockISOUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockStatus": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ]
  },
  {
    "LastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "MaterialCode": "na-XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationId": "XXXXX",
    "StorageLocationLastUpdated": "XXXXX",
    "StockAmount": [
      "0.000",
      "0.000",
      "0.000"
    ],
    "StockISOUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockUoM": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ],
    "StockStatus": [
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX",
      "XXXXX"
    ]
  }
]
```

Need help in writing a jolt spec so that we get a flattened Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more **shift** transformation to separate the content of the currently generated three objects triple so as to generate *3* x *3* = *9* objects by walking along with a component of the arrays start with **Stock**(I've picked ***StockStatus*** in this case), then prune all of the key names through use of an extra **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
     <body of the current spec>
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "StockStatus": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,LastUpdated)": "&3.&1.LastUpdated",
            "@(2,MaterialCode)": "&3.&1.MaterialCode",
            "@(2,StorageLocationId)": "&3.&1.StorageLocationId",
            "@(2,StorageLocationLastUpdated)": "&3.&1.StorageLocationLastUpdated",
            "@(2,StockAmount[&])": "&3.&1.StockAmount",
            "@(2,StockISOUoM[&])": "&3.&1.StockISOUoM",
            "@(2,StockUoM[&])": "&3.&1.StockUoM",
            "@": "&3.&1.StockStatus"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `&3` stands for going three levels up in order to reach the uppermost indices(they are `0`,`1`,`2`), which are one level above the `StockStatus` key's level, and `&1` to reach the indices of **StockStatus** array(they are `0`,`1`,`2` too) to separate each element groups into *3* x *3* = *9* different objects. The *ampersands* within the `@(2,Stock....[&])` keys represent looking up the indices of `StockStatus` array as well.

Comment: Thanks . what &3.&1 mean and  why we used StockAmount[&]?

Comment: Hi @ThiyagarajNarayanan , I've edited the answer with to express them. Best wishes.